# Serializing a list of enums in Json.net

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a solution in which I'm needing to convert a number of C# classes into their JSON format for a REST API. I'm using enums to avoid having to remember the strings to pass in for values when an enum would suffice.

To that end, one of the arguments is a List of enums. As I already have a class written using the JsonConverter, I thought I'd just pass this list of enums along to the WriteJson method as I would just a plain enum and it'd just automatically handle the list component of it behind the scenes somewhere. Unfortunately, this isn't the case. In my WriteJson method, I have the following:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
  var e = (SuiteType) value;
  switch (e) {
    case SuiteType.Full:
      writer.WriteValue("complete");
      break;
    case SuiteType.Partial:
      writer.WriteValue("partial");
      break;
  }
}
```

This gives the error about a bad cast when I try to cast it to the SuiteType because of course the inbound value is actually a List of SuiteType and not just a SuiteType. With that in mind, how could I handle this custom conversion (since it's not always a 1:1 between the enum names and the string or int values they'd output while still converting from a collection of such enums?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, as soon as I posted that, the answer occurred to me. Rather than mark the List property on the class object, such as:

```
[JsonProperty("types")]
[JsonConverter(typeof(SuiteTypeConverter))]
public List<SuiteType> Types { get;set;}
```

Instead, remove the JsonConverter from there and place it at the top of the enum definition as in:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(SuiteTypeConverter))]
public enum SuiteType {
...
}
```

And it works fine.